# how to fix: AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'get_message'?

Tags: discord.py

so every time i run this piece of code it comes up with the above error, and i was wondering if it was anything i was doing?

ive tried completely rewiting it but it keeps coming up with errors like

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attributes 'get'
```

here is the full code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global Loop
    print("active")
    execute_query("mydatabase.db", "UPDATE Members SET expPersonalBoost = 1")
    level_up(1, 1)
    activity=discord.Game(name="BOTNAME %s" % (str(buildVersion)))
    await client.change_presence(activity=activity)
    channel = client.get_channel(557970901614985226)
    LBoardExp = await channel.get_message(558236923181793280) #ERROR_HERE
    LBoardBal = await channel.get_message(558237158763397130)
```

the expected result was for the code to change the contents of a message however it came up with the attribute error instead

Answer (score 0):

A recent update changed `get_message` to [`fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message).  This is to distinguish functions that get information from the local cache, from functions that fetch information over HTTP.